# Finding a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ that takes values in a subset of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, time-series

This is the problem that I'm working on, for reference:

> For some $n\ge 3$, let $\varepsilon_1, \ldots , \varepsilon_n$ be i.i.d $N(0, 1)$. Set $X_1 = \varepsilon_1$ and $X_i=\theta X_{i-1}+(1-\theta^2)^{1/2}\varepsilon_i$ for $i = 2, \ldots , n$ and some $\theta \in (−1, 1)$. Find a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ that takes values in a
>   subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

So, the way I went about trying to tackle this question was by trying to figure out the probability that $X_i$ equals a certain value given that we know the value of $X_{i-1}$: in other words

$$P(X_i = x_2 \mid X_{i-1} = x_1)$$

The way I did this was by assuming that $X_{i-1}$ was a constant ($x_1$), and then figuring out the probability distribution of $X_i$ with this constant included (which is just $N(\theta x_1, 1-\theta^2)$). Is this method of determining the conditional probability correct/allowed?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Do you follow the hint below? You may be able to work the answer out from conditional densities, not probabilities. But the answer below hints at a direct proof.

Comment: Yeah, it took some working out, since my linear algebra is rather rusty, but I think I follow it now. Thanks! @StubbornAtom

Comment: Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

What you can do instead is solve the recurrence to get

$$X_i=\theta^{i-1}\varepsilon_1+(1-\theta^2)^{1/2}\sum_{j=0}^{i-2}\theta^j \varepsilon_{i-j}\quad,\,i=2,3,\ldots,n$$

Then express the vector $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)^T$ as a linear transformation of $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_n)^T$, i.e.

$$X=R_{\theta}\,\varepsilon$$

for some nonsingular matrix $R_{\theta}$. Since $\varepsilon\sim N_n(0,I_n)$, that would imply $X\sim N_n(0,R_{\theta}R_{\theta}^T)$.

So just write down the density of $X$ and apply Factorization theorem.

Comment: Hi @StubbornAtom, would you mind explaining the last step? I have written down the density (which is a function of $\theta$ and $X_1,\dots,X_n$) but I can't see how to find a sufficient statistic with only three components? I know I want to somehow factor the density as $f(T,\theta)\cdot g(X)$, but I can't see what the sufficient statistic $T$ should be.